# Passing a curl argumet -T to rest-client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, curl, rest-client

I have an API call for uploading a file and I came across -T option which does the same in curl call.

> curl -X PUT "**assetUrl**" -H "**authorization**" -H
>   "x-amz-acl:**amzAcl**" -H "**contentType**" -H "x-amz-date:
>   **amzDate**" -T **path/to/local/file**

How can I pass that -T option to rest-client library?

Answer (score 1):

Either of below should work fine

```
RestClient.post '/data', :myfile => File.new("/path/to/image.jpg",
         'rb')



RestClient.post( url,
      {
        :transfer => {
          :path => '/foo/bar',
          :owner => 'that_guy',
          :group => 'those_guys'
        },
         :upload => {
          :file => File.new(path, 'rb')
        }
      })
```